# concatinating .csv files to create one big .csv changing datatypes of columns to "object"

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pycharm, pandas framework and python 3.3 for my project. I initially have 200 .csv.gz files from which I want to create one big .csv file. Below is the code for it and it is working

```
import gzip
import csv
import glob
import os

pathname=os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/downloaded/*.csv.gz")
path=os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/downloaded")
#path = pathname+"/*.csv.gz" #folder containing all .csv.gz files
counter = 1 #counts total number of files read
files = glob.glob(pathname)
try:
    for file in files:  # read files one by one
        with gzip.open(file,'rt',encoding="utf-8",errors="ignore") as mycsvread:
            filecontent = csv.reader(mycsvread)
            if counter > 1:
                header = mycsvread.readline()  # skip header file
            with open(path+"/combinedcsv.csv", 'a') as mycsvwrite:
                datawriter = csv.writer(mycsvwrite)
                for row in filecontent:
                    datawriter.writerow(row)
except IOError:
    print("File not found")
except EOFError:
    print("No input")
else:
    counter = counter + 1
```

But problem is all the columns are getting converted to "object" datatype. I found this when I created dataframe and read big .csv file into it. here is `dataframe.dtypes` output:

```
 BEGIN_YEARMONTH       object
    BEGIN_DAY             object
    BEGIN_TIME            object
    END_YEARMONTH         object
    END_DAY               object
    END_TIME              object
    EPISODE_ID            object
    EVENT_ID              object
    STATE                 object
    STATE_FIPS            object
    YEAR                  object
    MONTH_NAME            object
    EVENT_TYPE            object
    CZ_TYPE               object
    CZ_FIPS               object
    CZ_NAME               object
    WFO                   object
    BEGIN_DATE_TIME       object
    CZ_TIMEZONE           object
    END_DATE_TIME         object
    INJURIES_DIRECT       object
    INJURIES_INDIRECT     object
```

Can you please tell help me out in retaining original datatypes of columns?

Comment: And what are original data types? Likely, your columns are not consistent in all rows and dates are not in *YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS* format. Also, I see no pandas code. In fact it is not an imported module. Why write to csv when pandas can read directly from csv?

Comment: @Parfait is right. It looks like your columns are not consistent and therefore pandas cannot safely coerce the data, so it will stick to object to be safe. I also prefer his indicated approach of reading in the csv's with pandas, and constructing/merging the dataframes within this lib. With your read+write process, you will never change data-types. CSV has never information about data-types and everything is inferred at read-time.

Comment: @Parfait: I will use this approach. I will read each file in dataframe and then merge it to create one big dataframe. But I have one more question. As I want to separate the code, I am writing different .py files for each modules. So How I use merged dataframe in other modules? Like If I want to use the mergerd dataframe in other code, will I be able to use it?

Comment: @sascha: thanks a lot. I haven't thought of that approach.